# How can I avoid "Data at the root level is invalid" Error in Maven task for Automation Testing on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-pipelines, appium, pom.xml, automation-testing, serenity

I am using Azure DevOps for a task related to Automation Testing. I need help with resolving these two errors that I am facing:

1-

##[warning]Failed to read /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/test/resources/features/matas/app/homescreen/InStoreModeScreen.feature. Error : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1..

2-

Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: **Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver** (Connection refused (Connection refused)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYvTz.png)

Please guide me which task can I use to install Appium Driver in a Build Pipeline(CI) on Azure DevOps? Also explain why is Appium Driver important to execute Automation Testing?

I tried these tasks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg2SR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK5Gr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGXIU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RIMq.png)

I am expecting that pipeline automatically performs steps mentioned in *InStoreModeScreen.feature* file in repository.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYOCp.png)

Right now, tests are not being executed even when pipeline runs successfully.

Serenity Summary Report: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KFbF.png)

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please run maven command on your local machine to run your test. 1. If it fails locally, the issue may be related to your project. 2. If it works locally, the issue may be related to the pipeline settings or the environment. [Set up a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents) on your local machine, run the pipeline again using it and check if it works.

Comment: Hi Ziyang Liu,

Thanks for your response. I am able to setup pipeline in a way that it is picking all test files but it returns same error for all files, i.e. Failed to read Error: Data at the root level is invalid.
Kindly note that all test case files in my repo have .feature extension. Can you confirm whether it is due to file format, pipeline is throwing above warning?

Comment: I need to know whether .feature files are valid files against which tests run successfully using CI/CD on Azure DevOps?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, DevOps pipeline supports .feature files which are used for test.  Based on the current error message, I am not sure whether it is a problem with your project itself or with the pipeline configuration. The DevOps pipeline just calls mvn to run your test, which is the same as using maven command locally. Therefore, I previously suggested that you run maven command on your local machine to run your test to eliminate the impact of the pipeline and narrow down the issue.